# Python: How to mmap memory that is shared with Linux Kernel?

Tags: python, shared-memory, mmap

I have a kernel module that uses shared memory to exchange data with a userspace app. I can use C to implement the userspace app and map that shared memory without any problem.

Now, when I try to use Python it always throws the error msg :

```
ValueError: cannot mmap an empty file
```

Does anyone know how to correctly handle this mapping?

Sample code:

```
import mmap    
import os      
     
filepath="/proc/file"        
fd = os.open(filepath, os.O_RDONLY)    
mmap_object = mmap.mmap(fd,0, mmap.MAP_SHARED,mmap.ACCESS_READ)    
  
txt=mmap_object.read()
```

Comment: Do you give a non-zero length to the C mmap version?

Comment: Can you post your working C code?

Comment: You use length 0 which tells mmap to use the current file size. Considering the error code, that means that the current file size is zero. I asked about the C code because its mmap doesn't accept 0 at all, so you have to be giving some other number. You could check `os.stat("/proc/file").st_size` to see if it is indeed 0.

Comment: The size of the file is indeed zero as it is a special file. If I give a non-zero value to mmap, it raises another exception ("ValueError: mmap length is greater than file size"). On the internet, there was a proposal to deactivate mmap size check since the C implementation of mmap does not do that, but that proposal was rejected (link: https://bugs.python.org/issue12556). I guess, the Python mmap class works only on regular files, which is very restrictive :(

Comment: In this link (https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/master/userland/kernel_modules/mmap.c), you can find how the kernel-shared memory is mapped in a C-based application.

Comment: Any idea about how to solve the issue?